# Django Many to Many - polymorphic

Tags: django, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

In a Django application, I have three models:

- Service
- Product
- AppliedTax

I want to create a many-to-many relationship between `Service` and `AppliedTax` and between `Product` and `AppliedTax`. Normally I would have an intermediate model (i.e. `AppliedTaxTaxable`) with three fields (applied_tax_id, taxable_type and taxable_id) and `taxable_type + taxable_id` would be a composite foreign key for each related model with `taxable_type` having as value the name of the related model (`Service` or `Product` in my case) and the `taxable_id` field the id of the related record of the respective model.

I understand how to make it work with raw queries, but Is there a "Django" way to do that with a ManyToMany relationship? So far I had no luck with that. I don't have much experience with Django, but I hope there is a way to do that without using raw queries.

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some thought, I did a better search and stumbled upon **django-polymorphic**. [Here](https://medium.com/django-rest/polymorphic-model-relations-55f1010738ec) is a pretty straightforward explanation on how it works, for a basic set up and it does what I am describing in my question. The implemented schema differs a bit from what my description, but in the end we will home one intermediate table for all associated models.